# Liferay + google openid HOW?

Tags: openid, liferay

Is there someone who knows how to use Liferay 5.2.3 the most up2date free version of liferay with google openid ? I've try to use the http://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id url but it doesnt work. For example with www.myopenid.com it works without problems.

After trying with http://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id I was forwarded to google signin page but after I authenticate and grand the liferay for permission, liferay doesn't handle the response correctly so I couldn't log in.

Answer (score 0):

You have logged in to your account the "classic" way, yes? You need to have an account in Liferay and, given that this is working, then associate that with your OpenId identity. Not using google OpenId myself, I guess that google gives you a URL that you can use as your identity token to paste into the proper input field in liferay.